# Can I add link to my images from code on my own wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress. I have started creating custom theme. I am getting my content via following method:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        the_content()
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

I added lot of images on my website. These images are automatically sizing from wordpress. I want to add hyperlink (link of same image) to all images in a post. But I don't want to do this manually one by one.

Following is example of what I want to achieve:

```
 <img src="sample.img" /> 

 //to convert 

 <a href="sample.img" class="mycustomclass"> 
   // Image link: 
   <img src="sample.img">
 </a>
```

Comment: is it a featured image? or you added it manually in editor?

Comment: @ZainulAbideen I am added in manually editor

Comment: So you can do it manually in the editor. Select the image and then click 'Link' icon in the toolbar.